# Designing of data structure to select values on combination of keys

Tags: java, data-structures, combinations

I have a problem where I analyzed and generalized to this level, which I need to solve for efficient performance

I get huge collection of items from database like 1_A_B, 2_A, 2_B, 2_A_C, 1_C, 1_B, 2_B_C and so on..

Now when user picks up **A** (he can pick up only Alphabets, based on that Numeric values should return), he needs to be get **2** as 2_A exists, which means 2 can be displayed on selection of A

if user picks up **B**, he will get both **2,1** and if he picks up B_C, he will get only **2**

Order of input is random. So how efficiently or which data structure I should design for the best performance maintaining optimum memory usage

I thought of going with `Map<Alphabets,List<Numerics>>` but combination of alphabets to show Numerics is not something easy [B_C and C_B should return same results and there will be many alphabet combinations]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this would be a good solution to your problem, 
but if your alphabets are fairly limited, I would parse and convert each alphabet to powers of 2s.

For example, I assign

```
A = 1 (2^0)
B = 2 (2^1)
C = 4 (2^2)
D = 8 (2^3)
```

.. and so on.

Then, I would use `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` to store the data.
In the HashMap, key is the sum of numerical values of Alphabets and the value becomes the list of numbers that are the prefixes of data.

For example, 
given `1_A_B, 2_A, 2_B, 2_A_C, 1_C, 1_B, 2_B_C` ,

1_A_B will be stored under map[3, {1}] and 2_A will be stored under map[1, {2}] and so on.
Thus the map for a given data set would look something like

```
3, {1} //1_A_B
1, {2} //2_A
2, {2, 1} //2_B , 1_B
5, {2} //2_A_C
4, {1} //1_C
6, {2} //2_B_C
```

When input B_C is entered, you can simply look up key with value 6 (B+C) and thus return 2 as the answer.

The above method will also work well with situations dealing with B_C and C_B as sum of B_C and C_B is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a

```
HashMap<String,Integer>
```

, it is better for sparse data.
Before you enter the string, parse it an sort it. This way B_C and C_B will be considered the same.
When you check for existence, also parse and sort before the check.

Edit: 
For each input you store 1 element in the hash table. For example: 3_C_A should be entered, after splitting and sorting as

```
<"AC",3>
```

To check for existence, for example "C" you need to search the keys of the hash map.

```
Pseudo-code
Foreach(key in hash.keys) {
    Print hash(key) if x found in key
}
```

Memory usage: O(n)
Search performance: O(n)

Comment: In the original problem, letter combinations seem to be able to have multiple values, such as "2,1" for B. Consider a HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> or a Multimap<String, Integer> from a library like [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).